# XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController don't work

Tags: ios, youtube-api

i have a problem - the XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController don't work now. I tried latest version, but no results. I find, that XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController could not parse direct Url. And this problem in few my projects. Any can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest commit of XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController fix it.

https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController/commit/5dded8ed5f62e6a1031e30bba0e4db3e7c96d251

Comment: This just stopped working for me last night…  and it's already fixed!!  thank you!!  so timely!!